# How Different is an IDE like DreamWeaver and a CMS like Drupal when Developing a Website

Tags: javascript, php, html, content-management-system, dreamweaver

can someone explain the difference between the CMS like Drupal and an IDE like DreamWeaver when developing a website.When do we use them to develop websites.

Comment: An IDE is a tool (like a text editor) for writing code; a CMS is a pre-built framework of code

Answer (score 1):

A CMS (content management system) is a pre-built framework which makes the process of creating webpages easier and focuses on allowing the user to easily edit the content post-production. This works well for blogs as it allows people who barely any technical knowledge write and manage blogs with ease.

An IDE - Integrated Development Environment usually mean something like Dreamweaver, XCode (for iOS app development) and Eclipse(for android app development). It usually includes a text editor, built in automation tools and a debugger. However IDE can also refer to simple text editors such as Sublime Text or WebStorm.

So in conclusion you would use an IDE as a tool that enables one to build websites where as CMS provides a framework to simplify the build process and allow for easier content management after the website is built.

Answer (score 0):

Which one to use depends purely on your requirements

if your requirement is simple

```
I suggest to use CMS
PROs
--> No need to have understanding of any Computer Languages
--> Fast to implement

CONs
--> Difficult to maintain changes
--> difficult to implement complex logic (unless there is a CMS plugin to solve your requirement)
```

but if your requirements is complex (say for example includes many UI Screens)

```
I Suggest to use IDE 
PROs
--> Will have full control over the code
--> Easy to maintain versions
--> can implement any requirement (* provided software is designed well)

CONs
--> needs a prior knowledge on computer language (like PHP and javascript for most of the websites)
```